# Does "withContext" create a new coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I have the following code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch {
        println("in sub coroutine ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
    println("before coroutine in main ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println("hello from coroutine ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        delay(1500)
        println("hello from coutoutine after delay ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
    println("after coroutine in main ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
}
```

The output is:

```
before coroutine in main main @coroutine#1
hello from coroutine DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1
in sub coroutine main @coroutine#2
hello from coutoutine after delay DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1
after coroutine in main main @coroutine#1
```

My understanding is that `withContext` switches the code to a new context where code is executed in a different thread, and the current coroutine is suspended until the code in the new thread is completed. But the original definition does not say anything about creation of new coroutine.

[Original definition](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) from kotlin.github.io:

> Calls the specified suspending block with a given coroutine context, suspends until it completes, and returns the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no one-to-one correspondance between threads and coroutines. When a coroutine resumes from suspension, it could resume on some other thread, depending on what the Dispatcher gives it.

`launch` and `async` create new coroutines. `withContext` does not create a new coroutine, it only shifts the context of the existing coroutine, which is why it's a suspend function (unlike `launch` and `async`).

Comment: Yeah that is part of confusion. In definition it is said that original coroutine is suspended? if this is the original coroutine which coroutine is suspended? I think am misreading something here, so just want to understand what is happening and where I am wrong.

Comment: I think their terminology could use some work. They say a coroutine is suspended and resumed later, but really that same coroutine is doing other work. So the specific meaning of "coroutine" is a little ambiguous. The Kdoc for the function says "suspends until it completes" but it doesn't say *what* it suspends. It suspends the suspend function that called it.

Comment: suspend function is executed inside coroutine, so what does it mean when you say it suspends the suspend function that called it? am just not able to understand it completely please bear with me.

Comment: When you call `launch` you pass it a suspend function lambda, the entry point of your coroutine, and the backend starts the coroutine by invoking it. Suspend functions can only be called by other suspend functions. When the docs for `withContext` say it suspends, it means that while it executes, the function that called it is suspended. So at the top level, within your `launch{}` block, the lambda itself is the suspend function that gets suspended when it calls other suspend functions.

Comment: Okay so suspension and blocking refers to thread. suspending a function means it does not have execution right now? I will read more about it. Thanks

Comment: Suspension is always used for coroutine but when you say here launch suspend function is suspended but what is happening to underlying coroutine or thread.

Comment: If I use suspend and blocking wrt thread then it makes sense. Earlier coroutine was scheduled on main thread, after withcontext coroutine shifted to other thread and main thread got suspended. Is it right reasoning?

Comment: A typical function runs from start to finish and fully occupies the thread it's running on. A suspend function releases its thread whenever it suspends (which it does by calling other suspend functions), and it might be resumed on some other thread, depending on what the current Dispatcher's behavior is. The term "coroutine" is analogous to "thread" in the sense that it is a sequence of things you program to happen, but not in the sense that it is an object that can have things happen to it.

Comment: Whatever happens to the thread a suspend function was using when it suspends is dependent on the Dispatcher. Dispatchers.Main posts execution to the main thread, so when a coroutine resumes on Main, its continuation gets posted to the Looper of the main thread. Dispatchers.Default and Dispatchers.IO have a thread pool where each thread is running in a loop, waiting for new jobs to be posted to them. So when a function needs to resume, they will pick a thread from the pool (preferably one that is not busy) and send the continuation to its loop.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand coroutine a bit better

Comment: Threads don't get suspended; functions do. The main Thread on Android (or in Swing, etc.) has a loop going and lives for the lifetime of the application. Jobs get posted to this Looper and it executes them in sequence as it receives them. Dispatchers.Main uses this existing mechanism and basically constructs Runnables out of coroutine continuations and posts them to the Looper.

Comment: So basically coroutine has a suspend function and a suspend function can call other suspend function and in this process calling function will be suspended. Coroutine can be scheduled on any thread as dispatcher decide, right?

Comment: One more thing coroutine does not get suspend, only function get suspended. Coroutine can be scheduled to run multiple suspend functions. But at so many places online no one says function got suspended.

Comment: That’s why I said I think the term coroutine is ambiguous. There is no actual object that is called Coroutine. It’s just a term to describe a flow of execution. We say the coroutine is suspended by a suspend function, but the suspend function itself is still running in that coroutine and might suspend it again before the first suspension resumes.

Comment: Ok this ambiguity has to be cleared up by kotlin guys.

Comment: Ok so now back to basics, what does launch do? What does it mean when they say launches a new coroutine?

Comment: We can get the coroutine name as I got in code in question.

Comment: You pass the `launch` function a lambda that is a suspend function. It will start that flow of execution for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're just misreading your output.

```
before coroutine in main main @coroutine#1
hello from coroutine DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1
in sub coroutine main @coroutine#2
hello from coutoutine after delay DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1
after coroutine in main main @coroutine#1
```

In this output, you have 2 coroutines:

- @coroutine#1 (via "runBlocking")
- @coroutine#2 (via "launch")

And two threads:

- main
- DefaultDispatcher-worker-1

No additional coroutine is created when doing "withContext". Your two coroutines are "runBlocking" and "launch".

Comment: Yeah that is part of confusion. In definition it is said that original coroutine is suspended? if this is the original coroutine which coroutine is suspended? I think am misreading something here, so just want to understand what is happening and where I am wrong.

Comment: It *does* suspend the current coroutine, which is why your last println gets printed last, even though the code within "withContext" has a 1500ms delay.

Comment: that is what am trying to understand which coroutine is suspended if withContext is not creating new coroutine.

couroutine1 before withcontext --> coroutine 1 in withcontext --> coroutine1 after withcontext

when coroutine1 got suspended?